# How to toggle class in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can toggle a class in a component.

I have my component that has two states: active and desactive. When I want to active it, I need add the class `active`.

Currently I'm using jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Component.js:

```
SiteApp.BookingBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
      actions: {
        open: function (element) {
          this.sendAction('open', this.$());
        },

        close: function (element) {
          this.sendAction('close', this.$());
        },
      }
});
```

Controller.js:

```
SiteApp.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    open: function (element) {
      element.addClass('event--active');
    },

    close: function (element) {
      element.removeClass('event--active');
    },
  }
});
```

It is working, but I have this feeling that Ember has something build in that will help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Ember's documentation on [Templates: Conditionals](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/templates/conditionals/). Essentially conditionals allow you to use expressions in your templates with variables declared in components/controllers. So, instead of accessing DOM in your components/controllers (which is not the Ember-way of doing things), you can do:

```
App.AComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    isOpen: false,

    actions: {
        open: function (element) {
            this.set('isOpen', true);
        },

        close: function (element) {
            this.set('isOpen', false);
        }
    }
});
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="{{if isOpen "event--active"}}">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: what about if this components is a bunch of boxes and i want hide the others if one is active?

Comment: You can either right your own template helper or use something like https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers that gives you more powerful conditionals.

Comment: just one more doubt.. shouldn't i use this in the controller? and only use the component to send action?

Comment: Controllers are only supposed to handle the display logic of your views. For more generalized logic controls, template helpers are preferred.

Comment: @celoxxx in terms of controller usage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwb3HvjpG3o&index=1&list=PLaKDKbFmAv-aLYGogQ63zzKeUpy_opDia

Also, if you want much faster and more detailed help getting started, join the ember-community slack: https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 10):

Or you could do

```
App.AComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    isOpen: false,

    actions: {
        toggleOpen: function (element) {
            this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
        }
    }
});
```

Hbs

```
<div class="{{if isOpen 'opened' 'closed'}}">
    ...
</div>
```